# How to get start date and end date of current month in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datefield

I have 2 DateFields named `startDate` and `endDate` I want to set `startDate`'s Selected date to Current months start date and `endDate`'s Selected date to Current months End date.
How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean this?

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class DateExample extends Sprite
    {
        public function DateExample()
        {
            super();

            var now:Date = new Date();
            trace("now: " + now.toString());

            var startDate:Date = new Date(now.fullYear, now.month, 1);
            trace("start: " + startDate.toString());

            var endDate:Date = new Date(now.fullYear, ++now.month, 0);
            trace("end:   " + endDate.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

output:

now: Fri Oct 21 00:15:09 GMT-0500 2011
start: Sat Oct 1 00:00:00 GMT-0500 2011
end:   Mon Oct 31 00:00:00 GMT-0500 2011